# My handler does not set the state - Material UI

Tags: reactjs

I am using the component "Dialog" from Material UI.

When I click on the button to close the Dialog (which triggers `handleCLose`), it does not set the state to `false`.
I read a similar problem here: [OnClick Listeners not working after closing full-screen dialog using react-material-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561139/onclick-listeners-not-working-after-closing-full-screen-dialog-using-react-mater)
but I have not managed to save it so far.

```
const Transition = React.forwardRef(function Transition(props, ref) {
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});


function Information() {

    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);
    };


    const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
        console.log(open)
    };

    return (
        <div onClick={()=>handleClickOpen()}>
            Information
            <Dialog
                open={open}
                TransitionComponent={Transition}
                keepMounted
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
            >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">{"Information"}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
                      Blablabla
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary"> // The function is here
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Information
```

Comment: state setters are async, so you may not see your updated value by console logging immediately after. If you move your console log right before the `return`, do you still not see the updated values?

Comment: Even outside the function, it tells me that the state has not been updated. I can also check that it has not been updated, because the `Dialog` box does not disappear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have wrapped your dialog in a `div` with an `onClick` function that sets the dialog to open. What is happening is that `onClick` is being called whenever you click inside the dialog. So even when you click the close button it is calling `handleClickOpen`. Try separating them:

```js
    return (
        <>  // Add wrapping fragment
            <div onClick={()=>handleClickOpen()}>
                Information
            </div> // close div here
            <Dialog
                open={open}
                TransitionComponent={Transition}
                keepMounted
                onClose={handleClose}
                aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
                aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
            >
                <DialogTitle id="alert-dialog-slide-title">{"Information"}</DialogTitle>
                <DialogContent>
                    <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-slide-description">
                      Blablabla
                    </DialogContentText>
                </DialogContent>
                <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                        Close
                    </Button>
                </DialogActions>
            </Dialog>
        </>
    );
}
```